# add an object and delete another object at the same time

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset, django-signals

I have two models in django named cattle and theft I would like to introduce a theft to delete the object gained. I have no idea if it is possible.

```
class Ganado(models.Model):
    unidad = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    raza = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=raza_choices)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=color_choices)
    nume_marca = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    lugar_marca = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=marca_choices)

class Hurto (models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField()
    ganado = models.OneToOneField(Ganado,null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in the following way using signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender= Hurto)
def hurto_eli_fichaganado(sender, **kwargs):
    for hurtos in Hurto.objects.all().select_related('ganado'):
        for ganados in Ganado.objects.all():
            if hurtos.ganado==ganados:
                ganados.delete()
```